# Custom map in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit

I am currently developing an iOS application using location.
But I want to have a customized map to show user's location, not the default map given by MapKit.

A map like this for example :

[image: Snapchat map]

Is it possible to achieve something like this in Swift 4.0 ?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `MKTileOverlay` - documentation is [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mapkit/mktileoverlay)...

As it says:

> You use tile overlay objects to represent your own tile-based content
>   and to coordinate the display of that content in a map view. Your
>   tiles can supplement the underlying map content or **replace it
>   completely**.

(my emphasis)

Answer (score -1):

This is how you can make a map show your live current location.

Full code:

```
    import UIKit
import MapKit


//import CoreLocation

class ViewController: UIViewController, UIScrollViewDelegate ,CLLocationManagerDelegate, MKMapViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet var map: MKMapView!

    var locationManager = CLLocationManager()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        locationManager.delegate = self
        locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()

    }


    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {

        let userLocation: CLLocation = locations[0]

        let latitude = userLocation.coordinate.latitude

        let longitude = userLocation.coordinate.longitude

        let latDelta: CLLocationDegrees = 0.05

        let lonDelta: CLLocationDegrees = 0.05

        let span = MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: latDelta, longitudeDelta: lonDelta)

        let location = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: latitude, longitude: longitude)

        let region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: location, span: span)

        self.map.setRegion(region, animated: false)

        let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
        annotation.coordinate = location
        annotation.title = "My current Location"

        map.addAnnotation(annotation)



    }


}
```

Note that you also have to add the permissions to the info.plist file
the permissions are:

Privacy - Location When In Use Usage Description

Privacy - Location Always Usage Description

Answer (score -1):

Here is how you can give fixed location and a pin in a map view

```
import UIKit
import MapKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var myMap: MKMapView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let latitude : CLLocationDegrees = 86.44999
        let longitude : CLLocationDegrees  =  54.39
        let latitudeDelta : CLLocationAccuracy  = 0.05
        let longituteDelta : CLLocationAccuracy = 0.05

        let myLocation = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: latitude, longitude: longitude)
        let mySpan = MKCoordinateSpanMake(latitudeDelta, longituteDelta)
        let myRegion = MKCoordinateRegion(center: myLocation, span: mySpan)

        myMap.setRegion(myRegion, animated: true)

        let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
        annotation.coordinate = myLocation
        myMap.addAnnotation(annotation)

      }  
    }
```